# поиск сущностей по параметрам

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, jpa

Как реализовать удобный фильтр по параметрам при работе с бд? Есть определенные параметры, к примеру цвет, длина, вес которые приходят с UI. В контроллере все это обрабатывается как-то. И уже на слое репозитория согласно параметрам надо извлечь нужные объекты. К примеру сначала выбирается допустим вес 20кг, а потом еще + параметр длина 2м, итого уже два параметра в запросе должно участвовать. И так до +5...10 параметров. Предлагать все Hibernate, Jpa, Spring jdbc, data-jpa.
Может есть какой-то незамысловатый способ это осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Вариант 1**. Используйте Apache Lucene либо Sphinx. Apache Lucene написан на Java, поэтому легко его интегрировать в проект на Spring. Sphinx запускается как отдельный процесс с общением по TCP (или через pipe), поэтому нужно писать свой менеджер подключений или использовать порт API на JAVA, который последний раз обновлялся лет 10 лет назад. Но Sphinx есть меньше ресурсов, а для Lucene нужно от 2 Гб RAM для нормальной работы.
2. **Вариант 2**. Создаете 3 таблицы:
   `item` - товар, `property` - свойство, `item_property` - соответствие свойства товару.

Например, будет:

```
item:
---------
id | name
--------- 
1  | IPhone

property:
---------
id | name
---------
1  | Вес
2  | Цвет

item_property:
-----------------------------
item_id | property_id | value
-----------------------------
1       | 1           | 5
1       | 2           | белый
```

Тогда выбирать вы будете через `INNER JOIN` и `UNION ALL`. То есть для запросов Hibernate вам не поможет - нужно будет использовать нативные запросы.

Comment: я сделал немного по другому. в две таблицы. типо такого: таблица item с полями id и name, и property с полями item_id и id(само значение, красный к примеру). То есть на каждое свойство своя таблица. Получается что для каждого свойства, то есть таблицы, надо создавать свой класс-сущность?

Comment: @cori, в вашем случае - да. Если только 2 таблицы, то вам будет тяжело делать поиск, потому что в вашем случае  сложно сделать различие в том, как называется тот или иной параметр. Если на каждое свойство у вас по таблице, то вам при добавлении нового свойства придется лезть в базу и код и создавать классы. Рекомендую воспользоваться вариантом 2, так как это стандартная схема.